# Create password for Mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, passwords

Helo.
I use Mysql and Java to create new program. This program run on single pc and my database create with my program. Anybody can copy the database that i create and open it on other pc that installed Mysql.
How can i prevent this happen.
Excuse me for my ugly english.

Answer (score 1):

To create a database from you'r Java app, you need a user with database creation grants.  I'm not sure to understand the issue, but simply don't give that username/pass to anyone.  This will prevent them to access you'r database.  Also, you could crypt/hash the password in the connection string in you'r java app.

Comment: I dont want use crypt/hash. If anybody copy .frm .myd files to another pc then can open it in Mysql server that run at pc.